# Cost of finding optimal elimination order in a planar tensor network?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dynamic-programming, parameterized-complexity, planar-graphs

Suppose we are computing a sum over $n$ factors which can be represented as a planar tensor network. What is the complexity of finding an optimal elimination order?

For example, take the following summation over 5 variables:
$$\sum_{v1,v2,v3,v4,v5} f_1(v_1,v_5)f_2(v_1,v_2,v_3)f_3(v_3,v_4)f_4(v_2,v_4,v_5)$$

Each variable $vi$ takes integer values in $1\ldots di$ and factor $f(a,b,c)$ is a multidimensional array indexed by $a,b,c$.
This is a tensor network because each variable occurs in exactly 2 factors, and we can represent it graphically by drawing factors as vertices and variables as edges in planar graph $G$

[image]

Given a sequence of variables, we eliminate variables in sequence order by summing out one variable at a time. For instance, starting with $v_1$, performing the first elimination reduces our problem to the following summation over 4 variables.

$$\sum_{v2,v3,v4,v5} f_*(v_2,v_3,v_5)f_3(v_3,v_4)f_4(v_2,v_4,v_5)$$

[image]

where
$$f_*(v_2,v_3,v_5)=\sum_{v1}f_1(v_1,v_5)f_2(v_1,v_2,v_3)f_4(v_2,v_4,v_5)$$

The cost of this elimination was $d1\times d2 \times d3 \times d5$ which is the cost of computing $f_*$ (the new vertex created  as we [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction) edge v1). As we continue this process we eventually end up with a scalar (another [example](https://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci2950-p/lectures/2013-02-28_junctionTrees.pdf)). We get total cost by adding up costs of individual eliminations. Optimal elimination order minimizes total cost. What is the complexity of finding optimal elimination order?

***Some known partial results***

**minimizing worst-step cost**

Suppose every variable in the summation ranges from 1 to $d$. Then at least one elimination step has a cost $d^c$ where $c$ is the carving width of $G$. For planar graphs, the "ratcatcher" algorithm takes $O(n^3)$ time to find elimination order where the slowest step has cost  $d^c$ (page 12 of [Branch and Tree Decomposition Techniques for
Discrete Optimization](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/educ.1053.0017))

**max degree 2**

Suppose every factor has degree 2 and each variable is allowed to have its own range $d_i$

$$\sum_{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5} f_1(v_1,v_2)f_2(v_3,v_4)f_3(v_4,v_5)f_4(v_5,v_1)=\text{tr}(ABCD)$$
[image]

Optimal elimination order can be found in $O(n \log n)$ time using algorithm by Hu/Shing: ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication#Hu_&_Shing_(1981)), [Matrix Chain Multiplication and Polygon Triangulation Revisited and Generalized](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.01777))

Comment: This question might get more attention on [cstheory.stackexchange.com](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: crossposted to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50794/complexity-of-optimal-elimination-sequence-for-a-planar-tensor-network

Comment: Related question when further restricting to trees https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/146680/generalizing-matrix-chain-problem-optimal-summation-in-a-tree