# Generalizing Matrix Chain problem: optimal summation in a tree

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

Matrix Chain Problem can be viewed as the problem of finding the optimal summation order in a path-structured tensor network. How hard is the problem if we extend it to trees?

For instance, take the following sum, written in [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Statement_of_convention)
$$A_i B^i_j C^j_k D^k$$

This corresponds to the [tensor network](https://tensornetwork.org/diagrams/) below:

[image]

There are 3 edges $e$, corresponding to indices $i,j,k$, each with their own dimension $d_e$. One possible summation order is below:

$$((A_i B_j^i) C_k^j) D^k$$

The number of multiplications, aka, total cost of this order is

$$d_i\times d_j + d_j\times d_k + d_k$$

Given a list of dimensions $\{d_e\}$, finding the order which minimizes total cost is equivalent to the Matrix Chain problem, solvable in $n \log n$ time ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication#More_efficient_algorithms)).

Take the following sum in Einstein summation notation:

$$A_{ij}B^{i}_{kl}C^j_{mn}D^k E^l F^m G^n$$

This corresponds to the tensor network below, binary tree of depth $D=3$:

[image]

There are 6 edges $e$, each corresponding to an index of dimension $d_e$. One way of computing the sum is the breadth-first search order

$$(((((A_{ij}B^{i}_{kl})C^j_{mn})D^k) E^l) F^m) G^n$$

Each step is a contraction of two tensors, requiring the number of multiplications which is the product of dimensions of all indices occurring in either tensor. IE, cost of computing $Y_i^l=X_{ijk}Y^{jkl}$ is $d_i\times d_j\times d_k\times d_l$.

Total cost of computing this sum in breadth-first search order is
$$d_j\times d_i\times d_k \times d_l +d_k\times d_l\times d_j\times d_m\times d_n+d_k\times d_l \times d_m \times d_n + d_l \times d_m \times d_n +d_m\times d_n + d_n$$

For a tensor network with $n$ tensors, forming a complete binary tree of depth $D$, given a list of dimensions $\{d_e\}$, what is the complexity of finding an order which minimizes total cost?

PS: if we allow leaves to have free indices (ie, dangling edges in this graph), this kind of representation is an instance of "Hierarchical Tucker Decomposition"

Comment: Try dynamic programming on subtrees.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus so if the naive approach of creating a message for every subtree is the best possible, this would make it a $2^{O(n)}$ problem

Comment: I don't think so. There should be a lot fewer subtrees. Consider what happens in the case of a path, which corresponds to the usual problem.

Comment: For the $O(n^3)$ alg in the case of path, we compute cost for each of the $n^2$ connected subgraphs, but here we have at least $2^{2^{D-1}}$ connected subgraphs..

Comment: someone suggested this paper -- it claims some progress towards polynomial algorithm for this problem https://dr.ntu.edu.sg/bitstream/10356/141943/2/Towards%20a%20polynomial%20algorithm%20for%20optimal%20contraction%20sequence%20of%20tensor%20networks%20from%20trees.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restrict yourself to *linear* contraction orders, i.e., you only contract tensors adjacent to the set of already-contracted ones, you can actually do this in polynomial time. I have recently proved this in my Master's [thesis](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1709391/1709391.pdf). The result follows from a fascinating yet non-trivial connection to *database join ordering* (I recommend [these](https://db.in.tum.de/teaching/ws1415/queryopt/chapter3.pdf) slides for join ordering). I also have a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.12332), but the thesis explains it properly.

If you want *general* contraction orders, i.e., you contract any two adjacent tensors, this is still an open problem (I learned this from the author of [Xu et. al](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.100.043309); that is also the reason they optimized for a weaker cost function, i.e., minimizing the largest intermediate tensor). Actually, the situation is similar in join ordering: the problem for tree queries is still open ([Moerkotte et al.](https://pi3.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/%7Emoer/querycompiler.pdf)).

However, you can provide *near-optimal* general contraction orders for trees. The key idea is to regard the linear order of the optimal algorithm as a chain and run the textbook cubic-time dynamic programming to build the optimal contraction tree given that order. This idea was first explored in [Neumann et al.](https://db.in.tum.de/%7Eradke/papers/hugejoins.pdf) (linearized dynamic programming) and has been shown to provide near-optimal solutions. Beyond the optimality result, I empirically validated that this holds for tensor networks as well. Recently, [Ibrahim et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.02895) proposed the same approach, but their linearization, i.e., the permutation of the leaves, is chosen greedily. The advantage of having an optimal algorithm for the linearization is that you are *at least* optimal in the regime of linear orders, so you can provide robustness that a greedy algorithm cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response! Connection to database join problem is useful to know